# <random> uniform_real_distribution with minimum distance between points

Tags: c++, random

I am generating a list of coordinates on a square using

```
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main(){

random_device rd;
long int seed = rd();
default_random_engine gen(seed);

double max=10.0, min=-10.0;
uniform_real_distribution<double> uni_real(min,max);

double random_x = uni_real(gen);
double random_y = uni_real(gen);

return 0;
}
```

I would like to ensure that there is a minimum distance between any two points. For my usage, this must hold when periodic boundary conditions are applied.

- Preferred solution would be a built in method in the `<random>` library to this. Is there any?
- Second best, any other package containing a fast way to perform the check (as long as it is easy to make use of).
- Worst case, I can write my own basic script which would be `O(n^2)` as I am not too concerned with efficiency right now. Unless, there is some easy algorithm to implement that can do this.

Other questions around where either dealing with the third point or with other environment from `<random>`.

Comment: You can put your points in a container. For nth point, check distance between existing ones and it and, if distance requirement is checked, add it to the list. It's not optimized but it's a starting point.

Comment: how many points do you need to generate?

Comment: Right now I am ok with around 5000 at the most. In a second moment, I would probably like a lot more, in the order of a million.

Comment: why do the points have to be random at all? are you targeting different shapes than a simple square? maybe you can give more details about your use case

Comment: if you need a function that generates sequentially a set of points, with those points' distances within range constraints, `O(n^2)` is about as good as you will get without some sort of adaptive graph to keep track of which points are eligible for further adjacent points' placement... imo anyway.

Comment: @m.s. I will use points in different configurations, I will have to do both arrangement on a regular grid and different random distributions. The reason I need the distances is that the list of point is fed to a voronoi tessellation software named voro++. Due to numerical errors numbers that are too close end up being interpreted as being the same and their tessellation is removed automatically by the software.

Answer (score 3):

While such sampling (which is equivalent to non-overlapping circles generation) is discussed on math.stackexchange, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2594/efficient-way-to-generate-random-points-with-a-predefined-lower-bound-on-their-p and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69649/generate-nonoverlapping-random-circles, I would like to point out to another potential solution which involves quasi-random numbers. For quasi-random Sobol sequences there is a statement which says that there is minimum positive distance between points which amounts to `0.5*sqrt(d)/N`, where `d` is dimension of the problem, and `N` is number of points sampled in hypercube. Paper from the man himself http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0378475406002382